# new to programming in Java - issues with Javac

Tags: java, javac

I am new to programming in Java and am trying to compile a Java source file but I keep getting the following message when I type javac Welcome.java

```
Welcome.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
     System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
               ^

  symbol: method printIn<String>
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error
```

any ideas on how to correct this?

Thanks.

Comment: Post your code. The problem isn't with the compiler, it's with your code.

Comment: Can you post the code after that statement? Whatever is following the print statement is causing the problem. Edit: nevermind, it looks like you just typod the method name.

Comment: Did you type `printIn` instead of `println`? Notice it's "print line", not "print in"

Comment: The character after the `t` is a lower-case `L`.  It's impossible to telI the difference in some fonts, including the one StackOverflow uses to display comments.  (I sneaked a typo into this comment.  Bet you can't find it.)

Comment: Blogname - Even though your problem has been fixed, you should note that your question was not "up to snuff" for SO.  If you have a compile error you should include *the exact* (copy/paste) error message *plus* enough of your code to see the context where the error occurred (and with the failing line somehow identified).  And be sure the code excerpt includes any relevant declarations.

Comment: It's still well short of being "up to snuff".  You didn't include the source code, plus you didn't do a copy/paste of the error info but apparently typed it in (inaccurately).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is a strongly case-sensitive language!Any mis-spellings or mis-typings will land you to erranous error.Take care from the next time DEAR,though,it's expected from you as a beginner in Java---you'll learn with time after getting these error messages.

The correct syntax for printing out a statement in Java is

```
System.out.println("Print here whatever you wanna print!");
```

The error which you are getting is all because you have mis-typed `printIn` instead of `println`----see `I` instead of `l`(alphabet `el` should have been there,not `ahy`)!

Comment: thanks for the responses, I actually typed the question wrong, in the source code the syntax I typed is System.out.println but the error message I get in the command prompt when I type javac Welcome.java has a ^ under the second period in System.out.println, any thoughts on why?

Comment: @blogname-Either send me a link to image or ask a fresh question.I am unable to understand your statement!

Comment: Seriously,it won't give any error.You're again confusing between `'I'` and `'l'`!

Comment: @blogname-Please accept the answer as it's a bad habit to leave the answer unaccepted if your problem has been solved.And,your next questions will not be answered positively by others if you'll continue doing this!

Comment: the font did not show up correctly on Stackoverflow.

Comment: the font did not show up correctly on Stackoverflow.  The syntax is correct as System.out.println,C:\Users\W313FleetStore>javac Welcome.java
Welcome.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
     System.out.printIn("Welcome to Java!");
               ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error                                                               I corrected the error in the source code to System.out.println as in el after k not ayh before jay and it still gives the same error that I've posted.

Comment: the font did not show up correctly on Stackoverflow.                                                      C:\Users\W313FleetStore>javac Welcome.java
Welcome.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
     System.out.printIn("Welcome to Java!");
               ^
  symbol:   method printIn(String)
  location: variable out of type PrintStream
1 error                                                               I corrected the error in the source code to System.out.println as in el after k not ayh before jay and it still gives the same error that I've posted.

Comment: I copied and pasted the command prompt screen but it's not showing up correctly on Stackoverflow.  There is a ^ showing up under the second period in System.out.printIn in the command prompt.  I typed System.out.println (l as in after k not I as in before jay) in the source code but the error is showing I typed System.out.printIn. as in I before jay not el after k.

Comment: This error reveals that only!Please rephrase a new question for that as this has been put off-topic!

Comment: Yes, the error was referring to the User folder and not the path and classpath folder versions where I saved the file to. Thanks for the answers.