# new to programming in Java

Tags: java

New to programming in Java
I keep getting the following error in the command prompt screen when I type javac Welcome.java.

Welcome.java:5: error: cannot find symbol

```
 System.out.printIn("Welcome to Java!");
           ^
 symbol:   method printIn(String)
 location: variable out of type PrintStream
```

1 error

The error in the command prompt is showing the code was typed using I as in before Jay in the source code although the syntax typed in the source code is l as in after k, in the line  in the source code.

This is a copy of the source code

```
public class Welcome {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
   }
}
```

Any answers on how to correct this?

thanks.

Comment: It's `println`, not `printIn`.

Comment: What happens if you change `println` to just `print`? @Wyzard while this seems logical, the OP explicitly says that isn't the problem.

Comment: You asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24847622/new-to-programming-in-java-issues-with-javac

Comment: are you sure your source coude is the same one you are compiling?

Comment: are you using any IDE.

Comment: I changed it println to just print and it gives the same error.

Comment: vermaraj - no I'm using notepad

Comment: Yaje -  I think it is, if it's not is there a way to check?

Comment: Is that your full, complete source code?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible you forgot to save.  Thus, you could have written out the new syntax but it's stored as the old syntax on the drive.  Check if this is what you did by opening up the file as-is, without changing it, and looking at the code.

Comment: It's also possible that you were editing the wrong file.

Comment: La-comadreja - It's possible I'm editing the wrong file, but I checked all copies of the file and the syntax seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

There is fault in your print statement. Change it to

```
System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
```

Comment: re-read his description of the problem

Comment: OP says _specifically_ this isn't the issue.

Comment: The Source Code was in the the user folder so I had to correct the fault in the print statement there from the i as in before jay to l as in after k. Thanks for all the answers.